# Is there a way to copy lines (ie Line337) from BBedit to Excel (automated) from a number of files

Tags: excel, xml, automation, bbedit

I have a large amount of XML files and I need to extract specific lines from each file (the same line numbers in each file) and place them in a single Excel document. ie, Line 277 of every xml file in to column 'A' of excel worksheet & line 269 of every xml into column 'B' of excel sheet.

Is this possible and, if so, how do i do it please?

To do this manually would take me several weeks. There are @20 lines i need to copy from each file and several thousand XML files.

If it isn't doable using the above method, is there another solution someone could recommend please.

Huge thanks

I have seen the question on here about detecting specific text within a line (and copying that' but this wouldn't apply in my case as the content of each line (eg Line337) will not always be the same.

I've (hopefully) attached a screenshot of a section of 1 XML. THe only reference to the data i need is in the Line number. ie Line182 will always be 'filename' with the actual filename shown in Line183 (this changes depending on the XML file. Apply this also to Line230 'Creation Date' which stays the same but the actual creation date is on Line231.

I've also attached a excel screenshot of, ideally, how the data needs to be displayed. Hopefully this helps

[XML screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxNYG.png)

[Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwDLw.png)

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I would use Powershell to parse the xml and extract the data by tags.  I would create a CSV file with output.  The csv can easily be imported into Excel if needed.

Comment: It sounds like a really bad idea to read XML by line number rather than by its logical structure.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MichaelKay, unfortunately there aren't any other common denominators in the xml files to identify - i only have the line numbers to go by :-{

Comment: @jdweng, based on your Powershell suggestion, would this work with 'line-numbers? I've added a screenshot of the XML data and a scfreenshot of theExcel sheet i would like to get as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple powershell script

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$filenames = Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\temp\test*.xml'
$csvFilename = 'c:\temp\test.csv'

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($filename in $filenames)
{
   $xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($filename)
   $newRow = [PSCustomObject]@{}
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Filename -NotePropertyValue $filename
   $rows = $xDoc.Descendants('row')
   foreach($row in $rows)
   {
      $elements = @($row.Elements('column'))
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $elements[0].Value -NotePropertyValue $elements[1].Value
   }
   $table.Add($newRow) | out-null
}
$table
$table | Export-CSV -Path $csvFilename -NoTypeInformation
```

Method 2 which skips the XML ident line when it is not UTF-8

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$filenames = Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\temp\test*.xml'
$csvFilename = 'c:\temp\test.csv'

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($filename in $filenames)
{
   $reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($filename)
   $reader.ReadLine()
   $xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($reader)
   $newRow = [PSCustomObject]@{}
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Filename -NotePropertyValue $filename
   $rows = $xDoc.Descendants('row')
   foreach($row in $rows)
   {
      $elements = @($row.Elements('column'))
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $elements[0].Value -NotePropertyValue $elements[1].Value
   }
   $table.Add($newRow) | out-null
}
$table
$table | Export-CSV -Path $csvFilename -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: thats Brilliant. That works for a single xml onto a single line in excel. 
How do i know do this for a batch of xmls onto a single excel sheet please?

Comment: I used Get-ChildItem with a wildcard to get all the xml files.

Comment: I added one line to code to add the filename to the csv file.

Comment: thank you for your input... this is exactly what i was looking for BUT, in all files on line179 there is a upside down '?' in red (which is flagging as hexadecimal code) which then stops the process being successful. If this is removed from the xml, the process works (but i'd have to delete it from the many hundreds of xmls). I've tried 'name mangler' which works on doing bulk changes but it doesnt find this character. Is there a way to eliminate line179 from the Powershell script?

<column name='value' type='string'>¿Mainconcept Video Media Handler</column>

Comment: Skipping the first line of the XML file sometimes helps.  I modified code above.  The Ident line usually contains UTF-8 and failures can occur when UTF-8 is not used.  Using ReadLine() which skips the first line sometimes will solve these issues.

Comment: thank you for spending time on this - I will give this a try later :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if the entries can be identified by property name rather than by line number, so a conventional XPath query such as `//row[column[1]='filename']/column[2]` should work just fine.

In XPath 3.1 I would do something like

```
collection('file:///c:/temp/dir?select=*.xml')/
  array{for $prop in ('filename', 'nb_streams', 'nb_progress', ...)
        return [string(//row[column[1]=$prop]/column[2])}
```

giving you one array for each row of the desired output, which you can then format into tab-separated values or whatever as required.

Comment: thanks Michael. I have managed to get the data extracted via Powershell using 'jdweng's method but will also give your suggestion a try too. Much appreciated.