# Generate xml files from template xml and csv value table

Tags: xml, powershell, templates, replace

I have template .xml file for a device, which contains placeholders for modbus addresses. I need to create 50 more based on a .csv list.
As a first step, I have created copies of template with names of the new devices:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (VRF_ListNames.csv) DO (
    copy VRF_equipment_template.xml ".\tmp\%%x.xml"
)
endlocal
```

Second step was to load .csv with values and replace the placeholders in all .xml files.

Code to load csv

```
$adresses = import-csv .\VRF_Adress.csv
```

Replace code:

```
    gci -r -include ".\tmp\*.xml" |
 foreach-object { $a = $_.fullname; ( get-content $a ) |
 foreach-object { $_ -replace 'XXNAMEXX', $CSVNAME `
                       -replace 'XXADR1XX', $CSVADR1 `
                       -replace 'XXADR2XX', $CSVADR2 `
                       -replace 'XXADR3XX', $CSVADR3 `
                       -replace 'XXADR4XX', $CSVADR4 `
                       -replace 'XXADR5XX', $CSVADR5 `
                       -replace 'XXADR6XX', $CSVADR6 `
                       -replace 'XXADR7XX', $CSVADR7 `
                       -replace 'XXADR8XX', $CSVADR8 `
                       -replace 'XXADR9XX', $CSVADR9 }  | 
set-content $a }
```

I need to cycle through all files, find the device name matching the file name in the first column of the csv and subsequently write all the $CSVADR values from the same row. Can anyone please advise how to do it. Thank you

Comment: I answered similar question on writing an xml file using XML Linq.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77839900/how-to-add-elements-to-xml-data-in-powershell/77839971#77839971  In this posting a read multiple files and put data into CSV format : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77799654/is-there-a-way-to-copy-lines-ie-line337-from-bbedit-to-excel-automated-from/77832887#77832887

Comment: There is templates based technology called XSLT for such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. Issue was, that I did not specify delimiter and csv was not processed correctly:

```
$devices = import-csv .\VRF_Adress.csv -delimiter ";"
$devices | ForEach-Object {
    $row = $_
(get-content ".\tmp\$($row.GROUP).xml" ) -replace 'XXNAMEXX', $($row.GROUP) `
                           -replace 'XXADR1XX', $($row.CSVADR1) `
                           -replace 'XXADR2XX', $($row.CSVADR2) `
                           -replace 'XXADR3XX', $($row.CSVADR3) `
                           -replace 'XXADR4XX', $($row.CSVADR4) `
                           -replace 'XXADR5XX', $($row.CSVADR5) `
                           -replace 'XXADR6XX', $($row.CSVADR6) `
                           -replace 'XXADR7XX', $($row.CSVADR7) `
                           -replace 'XXADR8XX', $($row.CSVADR8) `
                           -replace 'XXADR9XX', $($row.CSVADR9)  | 
    set-content ".\tmp\$($row.GROUP).xml"
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are making no attempt to check for special characters such as `<` and `&` which means you run the risk of producing ill-formed XML.